# the_content returns blank when adding SEO details

Tags: the-content, theme-thesis

I am using the Thesis theme and wanted a custom style for my pages. So I created a custom template while using thesis hooks and functions where applicable. I am doing this with a solution similar to the method [described here](http://website-in-a-weekend.net/extending-wordpress/create-custom-template-pages-thesis-theme/) so other contributors can use the themes in their pages as well.

I am getting the post's content by using the function the_content().

While this works normally and returns the contents of the pages, if I specify the SEO details (meta title, keywords, description etc), the_content() returns a blank.

Why should adding meta details to a page affect the_content like this? Would appreciate if someone can help me out with this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

could you post your template code? Maybe there is an error in your html. some unclosed tags or something.

also what result does this give you? is it also empty?

```
$content = get_the_content();
```

Comment: Found the problem. I had not used the_post(). For some reason it worked fine when there were no meta tags. But adding meta tags broke it. Getting data now. Thanks.

Comment: yeah , you'll need the actual post before you can get any content :) good thing you found the problem.